# insert textbox in a geoshow plot

Tags: matlab

I am using a code as below for a geoshow plot:

```
figure1 = figure;
load coast;
axes1 = axes('Parent',figure1,'FontSize',12,'DataAspectRatio',[1 1 1],'CLim',[0 4000]);
box(axes1,'on');
grid(axes1,'on'); 

geoshow(lat, long,'Color', 'black');
geoshow(latpr, longpr,'Color', 'blue'); 
geoshow(Lat_receiver,Lon_receiver,'DisplayType','point','Marker','.','MarkerSize', 30,'MarkerEdgeColor', 'green');
```

latpr, longpr is the set of data of a path that I want to show. Now I want to  insert a text in the plot that is lat, long of the starting point 
**(latpr(1,1), longpr(1,1))** and of the last point **(latpr(end,1),longpr(end,1))**.
How to insert the text?

Comment: hi so did you try the textm function?

Answer (score 0):

There is the [textm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/textm.html) function which can be used to project text annotations on map axes.

Something like this should work:

```
textm(latpr(1,1), longpr(1,1),'Your string');
```

and likewise:

```
textm(latpr(end,1), longpr(end,1),'Your string');
```